# PANDAS drop a range of rows from df

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

I want to drop m number of rows from the bottom of a data frame.  It is integer indexed (with holes).  How can this be done?

pandas == 0.10.1
python == 2.7.3

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Use slice to select the part you want:

```
df[:-m]
```

If you want to remove some middle rows, you can use `drop`:

```
df.drop(df.index[3:5])
```

Comment: How can do it when is a dataframe indexed by datetime. I tried `data_0 = data_0.drop(data_0.index['2016-01-28 12:00:00':'2016-01-28 12:02:30'])` to drop just this interval, but u have an error: 
`AttributeError: '_IXIndexer' object has no attribute 'drop'`

Comment: what is the type of data_0?

Comment: sorry the error is `IndexError: invalid slice`, data_0 is just a dataframe with three columns indexed by datetime

Comment: why not try df.reset_index() and drop with index again?

Answer (score 6):

an example where the range you want to drop is indexes between x and y which I have set to 0 and 10

selecting just the locations between 0 and 10 to see the rows to confirm before removing

```
x=0 # could change x and y to a start and end date
y=10 
df.loc[x:y]
```

selecting the index

```
df.loc[x:y].index
```

so to remove selection from dataframe

```
df.drop(df.loc[x:y].index, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
df.head(len(df) - m)
```

Comment: Or alternatively: `df.head(-m)`

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `iloc` method, which uses a position of rows/columns in the dataset rather than the actual index. So to remove the last `m` rows you can use:

```
df.iloc[:-m]
```